# Thread method doesn't seem to run.(Override the run() method)

Tags: java, networking

im making a server for an application, and I made a thread for accepting user's.

but it seems that it doesn't come to my overrided method run()

it doesn't give me an error or such it just doesn't run.

Here is the code:

This is the Client listener

```
package org.walking.server.listener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
/*
 * Walking client listener!
 */
 public class WalkingCL {
private SwingWorker work;


ServerSocket server;
 public boolean listening = true;

public void acceptclient(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Created server socket");

        server = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while creating ServerSocket on port 4444");


        e.printStackTrace();
    }
work = new SwingWorker<Object,Void>(){
    public Object doInBackground(){

        while(listening){
            try {
                new WalkingCLT(server.accept()).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error while making thread!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return listening;

    }
   };
 }
}
```

Here is the client listener thread:

```
package org.walking.server.listener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import java.net.Socket;
/*
 * Walking Client listener Thread!
 */
public class WalkingCLT extends Thread {
private Socket client;

public WalkingCLT(Socket client){
    super("Walking client listener thread!");

    this.client = client;

}
@Override
public void run(){
    System.out.println("HELLO?");
    try {
        System.out.println("User:" + client.getInetAddress() + "connected!");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));


        out.println("HELLO?");
        out.flush();



        out.close();
        in.close();
        client.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

I've put some println statments to see if it comes to that but I only see this:
Server stacktrace:

> Created server socket

Client stacktrace:

> Panel Created!
>   Your connected!

Hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only creating an instance of the SwingWorker task. You are missing a call to work.execute() or work.doInBackground() by some helper class. You need to look at the ExecutorService and how to use it to [submit and execute SwingWorker tasks](http://blogs.oracle.com/swinger/entry/swingworker_throttling_and_monitoring). There is also a small code snippet in the [Future documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: Thanks you so mutch! love this site!